# Flutter. Не могу загрузить третье окно. Черный экран

Tags: flutter, dart

У меня в приложении есть три страницы. С первой на вторую переход происходит, а со второй на третью почему-то черное окно. Я разделила в разные классы MaterialApp и собственно первую страницу. Из первой страницы вызываю вспомогательный класс, передаю в него котекст, а из вспомогательного класса уже вызываю вторую страницу, а из второй вызываю третью, передавая тот самый первый контекст. Что я делаю не так?

Да, действительно не хватало Scaffold. И все же я немного запуталась. На первой странице у меня Scaffold с AppBar, в body указана вторая страница. На второй странице у меня кнопка ElevatedButton, пишу в onPressed:

```dart
Navigator.of(mainContext).push
            (
              MaterialPageRoute<ConnectorDetails>
              (
                builder: (BuildContext context)
                {
                  return ConnectorPage(details.connectors[i], mainContext);
                }
              )
            );
```

В ConnectorPage:

```dart
return Scaffold
    (
      body: Center(child: Text('123', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)))
    );
```

Но у меня пропадает AppBar. Что я опять упускаю? Или его заново создавать на третьей странице?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Извините, пока сложно разобраться как правильно здесь форматировать текст и вставлять картинки.

---

Не знаю насколько это правильно, но мне все же пришлось создавать AppBar на третьей странице. Как изменить только body - я пока не нашла.

---

Все, что мне пришло на ум - я создала отдельный виджет AppBar, туда передаю что мне надо отображать. И применяю его на нужных мне страницах.

```dart
class AppBarWidget extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget{
  final Station station;
  AppBarWidget(this.station);

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
        title: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Станция ' + station.label),
            Text(station.address),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: прикрепите код)

Comment: Navigator.of(mainContext, rootNavigator: true).push
            (
              MaterialPageRoute<ConnectorDetails>
              (
                builder: (BuildContext context)
                {
                  return ConnectorPage(details.connectors[i], mainContext);
                }
              )
            );

Comment: @Лакшми от вас просили код ConnectorPage. Прикрепить код можно нажав на кнопку `Править` под вопросом.

Comment: Похоже, что внутри ConnectorPage не используется Scaffold виджет

Answer (score 0):

У каждого Scaffold свой собственный Appbar. Вы можете создать статический виджет AppBar и вызывать его в любом своём Scaffold